How to add dynamic annotations layer in Apache Superset?
I would like to change the annotations based on the selected filter. I have a drop down filter and I want to show different horizontal lines based on the input filter on a line chart. Is it possible to change the annotation layer based on filter selection? Do I need to modify the datasource SQL?

I want to show different UCL and LCL lines for selected model from the filter drop down menu in the left panel.
Any help is much appreciated.
I have added the static annotation layer but I am not sure how to add or dynamically apply different values based on applied filter using SQL.
